# Passing Dropbox file contents to an Azure Function from a Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I am trying a sample app with the workflow

1. Wait for new file (csv) in dropbox folder
2. Load the file contents
3. Pass the file contents to an azure function to further process

I am getting stuck on how to pass the file contents to the azure function. I keep getting an unsupportedmediatype error with  "Message": "The WebHook request must contain an entity body formatted as JSON

How do I get the output of the second stage into a function?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I typically do in those scenario's is create a json-body for the Function and add the messagecontent I want to sent to the function as a Base64-string as a part of the json-body (eg. Payload, or Body).

Similar approach on how Logic Apps handles certain media types at runtime.

```
{"OriginalFileName" : "myfile.csv", "PayLoad" : "ContentBase64String"}
```

Comment: Thank you , it was rather obvious once you said it lol. On to the next problem!